# Polymer 2.0: pass this to another element. Making a comments section

Tags: javascript, this, polymer-2.x

***So basically what I'm struggling with is how to pass the reference of the parent element to its child element i.e the custom remove element?***
can anyone please help me out!

*******************this is the el-insert element********************
    // this element recieves data from another element(username and comment)

```
<link rel="import" href="./remove.html"> 
<dom-module id="el-insert">
    <template >

        <div id="userComment"><span>{{username}}</span>:&nbsp;{{saveComment}}</div>
        <input id="edit"  type="text" value={{saveComment::input}}>
        <hr>
        <reply-comment></reply-comment>
        <button on-click="edit">Edit</button>
        <remove-comment ></remove-comment>

    </template>
    <script>
        class elInsert extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'el-insert'; }
            static get properties(){
                return {
                    saveComment:{
                        type:String,
                        notify:true
                    },
                    username:{
                        type:String,
                        notify:true
                    }




                }//return ends
            }
            edit (){
                $(this.$.userComment).toggleClass('hide');

                var display = $(this.$.edit).css('display');
                if(display == 'none'){
                    $(this.$.edit).css('display','block');
                }else{
                    $(this.$.edit).css('display','none');
                }     
            }




          }

          window.customElements.define(elInsert.is, elInsert);        
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

***************the remove button element******************

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"> 
<dom-module id="remove-comment">
    <template>
        <button on-click="remove">el-Remove</button>

    </template>
    <script>
        class removeComment extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'remove-comment'; }
            static get properties(){
                return{

                }//return ends
            }
            remove(){
                var element = this.parentNode.host;
                $(element).remove();
            }



        }
        window.customElements.define(removeComment.is,removeComment); 
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

This code works perfectly for me.
But how will I do the same thing using fire or dispatch as mentioned in the answer by ***Nicolas***.
How to pass event details from parent element to child element?
Also, I want to make this element reusable so that I can simply drop it into another place like in a reply to delete that also.
(Also, I'm new very new to polymer so if there is anything else that I can improve upon in this code then please let me know)
I hope now you guys can help me out.

Comment: I guess a little more context is needed to see what u are trying to do... in most cases it helps to show your failed attempts code.

Comment: i have made some changes, please check!

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to do that - in general you should just pass properties to the child element and catch events from the child in the parent elements.

`properties go down and events go up -`

In you case you do not have to pass anything to the child element. The child element should just fire an event and the parent should respond to it when it catches it.

Something like that:

```
<dom-module id="child-element">
  <template>
    <div on-tap="_deleteComment"></div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class ChildElement extends Polymer.Element {
      ...
      _deleteComment() : {
        // fire event to be caught by parent
        const deleteEvent = new CustomEvent('deleteComment', {detail: {
          whatever: {
            you: 'want',
          },
        }});
        this.dispatchEvent(deleteEvent);
      } 
    }
    ...
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <template>
    <child-element on-delete-comment="_deleteComment"></child-element>
  </template>

  <script>
    class ParentElement extends Polymer.Element {
      ...
      _deleteComment(evt) : {
        // handle evt
      } 
    }
    ...
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

@daKmoR is right - more context and some code would help -

Comment: I have made some changes! please check

Comment: So when you click on the "remove button", you just want to call the "remove" method from the parent, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly!
And also How can I pass the data of the event down to the remove-comment element.